# Invalid conversion from unsigned char* to char*

Tags: c++, char, signed, unsigned-char

Here is a code -

```
  1 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  2 {
  3     signed char S, *psc;
  4     unsigned char U,  *pusc;
  5     char C, *pc;
  6 
  7     C = S;
  8     C = U;
  9 
 10     pc = psc;
 11     pc = pusc;
 12 
 13     return 0;
 14 }

$ gcc test.cpp -o a
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:10:7: error: invalid conversion from ‘signed char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
test.cpp:11:7: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
```

This is compiled on gcc version 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.10 on an Intel 32-bit machine.

Considering that **`char` type is `unsigned char` on x86.** -

If assignments on line 7 and 8 for non-pointer types are Ok, why errors are thrown for pointer types on lines 10 and 11 ?

Also, should `C = U` succeeds without requiring a cast?

Comment: Are you familiar with the term ["strict aliasing"](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) ?

Comment: Reading that stuff ...

Comment: `-fpermissive` could help you, and ignore this annoyance. Just from time to time you might want to temporarily remove the tag again and see if your compiler finds other errors than this one in your project that you *should* worry about.

Comment: Also note you can do this through the use of `void*`s, if you don't want to use a compiler flag. For example `void* pc;` would allow this to happen, and to dereference you would have to do `*((char*)pc)`. Alternately you could just use a middle-man technique to not have to bother with the cast `(char*)pc` whenever you dereference, such as `void* pc_; pc_ = pusc; pc = pc_;`, at the expense of an unnecessary `sizeof(ptr)` bytes extra in the stack.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, it is important to stress the fact that `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are all **different types**. Section 4.10 of the C++11 Standard defines the three possible standard pointer conversions between pointers of different types:

> 1 . A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion is called a null pointer conversion. Two null pointer values of the same type shall compare equal. The conversion of a null pointer constant to a pointer to cv-qualified type is a single conversion, and not the sequence of a pointer conversion followed by a qualification conversion (4.4).  A null pointer constant of integral type can be converted to a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. [ Note: The resulting prvalue is not a null pointer value. —end note ]

This is not relevant, since we don't have null pointers of type `nulltptr_t` here.

> 2 . A prvalue of type “pointer to cv T,” where T is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv void”. The result of converting a “pointer to cv T” to a “pointer to cv void” points to the start of the storage location where the object of type T resides, as if the object is a most derived object (1.8) of type T (that is, not a base class subobject). The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the
>   destination type.

This cannot apply, since the destination type is not `void`. Finally,

> 3 . A prvalue of type “pointer to cv D”, where D is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv B”, where B is a base class (Clause 10) of D. If B is an inaccessible (Clause 11) or ambiguous (10.2) base class of D, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. The result of the conversion is a pointer to the base class subobject of the derived class object. The null pointer value is converted to the
>   null pointer value of the destination type.

`signed char` is not a base class of `char`, so not even this applies.

Therefore, an implicit, standard pointer conversion from `signed char` to `char` cannot be performed.

On the other hand, conversions between values of integral types are permitted according to what specified in Paragraph 4.7.

Comment: I think, it is important to emphasize, that `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` are 3 different types. I suspect the question comes from a misconception, that `char` is either `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 3):

C++ don't have automatic pointer conversion, it does not matter what are the pointer types on each side of the assignment, if they are different, you need a cast.

Answer (score 2):

`char` is a distinct type from `unsigned char` and `signed char`. It is only guaranteed to have equivalent value representation to one of them, but it is still a distinct type. You therefore cannot convert from either `unsigned char*` or `signed char*` to `char*` (that is, unless you use a `reinterpret_cast`). C++ just doesn't allow pointer conversions between distinct types like this, because then one type could masquerade as another.

However, a conversion from either `unsigned char` or `signed char` to `char` is perfectly fine because it just involves a conversion of its value.

Consider it this way: you can convert an `int` to a `float`, but you can't convert an `int*` to a `float*`.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but as said above, when you assigned "C = S; C = U;", C++ automatically converts it, kinda like if you do "char x = "h"; printf("%i", x);". However, pointers point to a specific location in memory, and that location has a size. So while converting sort of just looks at the values from a different angles, pointing to different values may involve changing the size of the value that is being pointed at.